# is it possible to use voting classifier for LSTM?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, ensemble-learning

here am trying to use a voting classifier on output from LSTM, BILSTM, GRU, AND BIGRU but getting the ValueError: The estimator Sequential should be a classifier error. how to resolve this error, any help in this regards is highly appreciated.
here is the code am trying to run.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
#create a dictionary of our models
#nn = KerasClassifier()
#nn._estimator_type = "classifier"
estimators=[('lstm', model1), ('bilstm', model2), ('gru', model3),('bigru',model4)]
#create our voting classifier, inputting our models
ensemble = VotingClassifier(estimators, voting='hard')
#fit model to training data
ensemble.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

here Is the complete error message

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-6474190dd669> in <module>()
      9 ensemble = VotingClassifier(estimators, voting='hard')
     10 #fit model to training data
---> 11 ensemble.fit(x_train, y_train)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/ensemble/_base.py in _validate_estimators(self)
    247                 raise ValueError(
    248                     "The estimator {} should be a {}.".format(
--> 249                         est.__class__.__name__, is_estimator_type.__name__[3:]
    250                     )
    251                 )

ValueError: The estimator Sequential should be a classifier.
```

Comment: You need to use KerasClassifier for that, it is even there in your code (but commented).

Comment: @ Dr snoopy if uncomment that am getting following error                       AttributeError: 'KerasClassifier' object has no attribute '__call__'